# WSDL Response without body element

Tags: soap, soa, tibco-business-works, tibco-designer

I've been tasked to create a SOAP web service and the response isn't supposed to have the body element like below

```
<SOAP-ENV:Envelope xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"><SOAP-ENV:Header><ns0:Response xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:ns="http://www.tibco.com/schemas/Schema.xsd8" xmlns:ns0="http://www.tibco.com/schemas/Schema.xsd8"><ns0:ResponseRefId>236514</ns0:ResponseRefId><ns0:ResponseCode>9999</ns0:ResponseCode><ns0:ResponseMsg>Authentication Failed, try again with correct credentials</ns0:ResponseMsg>      </ns0:Response></SOAP-ENV:Header></SOAP-ENV:Envelope>
```

my concern is whether it's possible to create a SOAP service that has a response with no body element. I am using Tibco BW 5 to create the service.

Answer (score 0):

You should add some more details to your question. What are you trying to achieve by using SOAP?
SOAP palette and BW SOAP activities automatically create the structure of the SOAP message. In SOAP the [BODY is a mandatory element](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/soap/soap_message_structure.htm)
TIBCO BW has a [SOAP Palette in their documentation](https://docs.tibco.com/pub/activematrix_businessworks/6.2.2/doc/html/GUID-124D810E-DEEC-45AD-8B13-6A902C414B02.html). You should refer to the documentation for further reference.

I suggest you expand the question to help you better.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I just wanted to know if the body element is mandatory.